# Let a, b, c be the sides of the triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let a, b, c be the sides of the triangle and A, B, C be the angles opposite to these sides respectively. If $\mathrm{\sin(A-B) = \frac{a}{a+b}\sin A\cos B - \frac{b}{a+b}\cos A\sin B}$ then prove that the triangle is isosceles

I have tried this by just applying the formula of $\sin(a-b)$ and tried to simplify a bit by trigonometry but can't find the right approach to prove the triangle isosceles please help me.

Comment: Edit your question and write in $$

Comment: What you have tried is correct and it does lead to the answer, why not try it again carefully?

Answer (score 5):

$$\sin(A-B) \;=\; \sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B$$ $$\quad\quad\quad =\; \frac{a}{a+b}\sin A\cos B - \frac{b}{a+b}{\cos A\sin B}. \quad\text{(given)}$$

Rearranging terms gives us

$$b\sin A\cos B = a\sin B\cos A.$$

As $\;a=2R\sin A,\;$ and $\;b=2R\sin B$,

$$\sin A\sin B(\cos A-\cos B)=0.$$

In a triangle, $\sin A$ and $\sin B$ can't be zero, so, $$\cos A = \cos B \;\implies\; A=B.$$